# Button position in android

Tags: android, layout, button, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make some "Chat view" with speech bubbles like on the SMS iPhone app.
This is a row I have done in the xml editor :

http://img44.imageshack.us/i/xml.png/

But when I launch my application, I get this :

http://img59.imageshack.us/i/resultt.png/

I don't know why the button to answer is so far away from my Relative layout border! This is the xml code of the speech bubble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bulle_chat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewPhoto"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="8sp"
        android:src="@drawable/lady">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageViewPhoto"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewPseudo"
        android:text="Pseudo"
        android:textColor="#242424"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_below="@id/TextViewPseudo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewDate"
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageViewPhoto">
    </TextView>
    <Button android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonAnswer"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_width="40sp"
        android:layout_margin="8sp">
    </Button>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageViewPhoto"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="BlbalblablbalbalbalbalbalablabalbalablaballabalbBlbalblablbalbalbalbalbalablabalbalablaballabalbalbalaBlbalblablbalbalbalbalbalablabalbalablaballabalbalbalablablaalbalabla"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewMessage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ButtonAnswer"
        android:paddingBottom="15sp">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the adapter getView() method (pseudo = nickname):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ctx.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row, null);
    TextView pseudo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewPseudo);
    TextView date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
    TextView message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewMessage);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPhoto);
    Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.ButtonAnswer);
    b.setId(position);
    b.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) ctx);
        
    pseudo.setText(listMessages.get(position).getPseudo());
    pseudo.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    date.setText(listMessages.get(position).getDate());
    date.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        message.setText(listMessages.get(position).getText());
    message.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
    message.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL);
        
    if (listMessages.get(position).getThumb()!=null){
        icon.setImageBitmap(listMessages.get(position).getThumb());
    } else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown);
    }
    return v;
}
```

As you can see, I set the layout alignment parent right and top to true but it doesn't work. Another problem: if I want to change the background of my button, this one disappears!

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you set a margin to go around the entire button. Try doing just a margin for the top and none for the right. Also, I could be wrong but isn't sp just for text and dp is for widths and whatnot?

Go from

```
android:layout_margin="8sp"
```

to

```
android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
```

Comment: It looks like for some reason the end of the layout or view pane, whatever you want to call it, ends before the message bubble ends on the right.  Is this view a child of another view?  It seems like it could be bigger.

Comment: Yes, I use this into a ListView, and this speech bublle is for the list rows.

Comment: I think whats happening is that you are on the top right of the relative layout you posted here but the space given by the list view isn't as much as it should be.  What I mean by that is that the list view is telling the relative view that it can only go so far over to the right.  You should see if you can give the relative view more space.

Comment: Ok you gave me an idea, I replaced all the margins by paddings (so I had to set paddings on the root relative layout and remove margins from the button, image, ..) and that works fine!

and for the problem of the button background, I probably made a mistake on the destination folder when I create my xml layout, it might not be in"Drawable" folder, I will try others.

Thank you Mike!